# Keras looped execution still looking for layers in previous iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I recently built a small grid search functionality (basically just a loop that goes through a a few different neural network architectures) in Keras and ran into a rather strange problem.

Let's take as an example that I'm using the following list for my grid (its not really a grid because there is only one hyper-parameter but I'll still call it that) :

```
layerListGrid = [] 
layerListGrid.append([5,5,5])
layerListGrid.append([10,10,10])
layerListGrid.append([100,100,100,100,100])
```

In other words, I want to consecutively three neural networks, each time with dense layers as described above.

To execute this, I do the following

```
#start grid loop
for layerList in layerListGrid:

    #define model structure
    init = keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(mean=initializerMean, stddev=initializerStdDev, seed=None)    

    model = Sequential()
    firstEntry=True
    for layer in layerList:
        if firstEntry:
            model.add(Dense(layer, activation=activation, input_shape=(inputSize,), kernel_initializer=init)) #first hidden layer
        else:
            model.add(Dense(layer, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=init))
        if dropoutRate>0.0:
            model.add(Dropout(dropoutRate))
        firstEntry=False

    model.add(Dense(1, activation=finalActivation, kernel_initializer=init)) #outputLayer
    model.summary()

    #compile model
    sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=learningRate, momentum=momentum, decay=decay, nesterov=False)
    model.compile(loss=loss,
                  optimizer=sgd,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    #define callbacks
    startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    startTimeText = startTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    tensorboard = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./TFLogs/'+startTimeText, histogram_freq=1, write_graph=True, write_grads=True, write_images=False)

    #fit model
    history = model.fit(trainX, trainY,
                        batch_size=batchSize,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        verbose=1,
                        validation_data=validationData,
                        validation_split=validation_split,
                        callbacks=[tensorboard]
                        )
    print('Fitting done')
    score = model.evaluate(testX, testY, verbose=0)
    print('Test loss:', score[0])
    print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Now, the first time the loop is run (i.e. for the first "layerList") the code executes correctly. Then the second loop trains its first epoch and then terminates right at the end (which, based on the error log below, is when the tensorboard callback triggers). It then throws an error, complaining that the input for "dense_1" is in the incorrect format. "dense_1" is the unique name given by Keras to the first dense layer from the **first** loop that was executed! In the second loop, the first dense layer is actually called "dense_4". There seems to be some kind of memory pointer that persists outside of the loop, but I can't figure out what it is. Has anyone ever encountered something like this, or does someone have a recommendation on how I could get around this?

Below is the stack trace

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/username/Repo//dfc/Analytics/tf_modeling/20170919_DFC_TF_dev.py", line 174, in <module>
  callbacks=[tensorboard]
File "/home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 867, in fit
  initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
File "/home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1598, in fit
  validation_steps=validation_steps)
File "/home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1203, in _fit_loop
  callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
File "/home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 77, in on_epoch_end
  callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
File "/home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 777, in on_epoch_end
  result = self.sess.run([self.merged], feed_dict=feed_dict)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
  run_metadata_ptr)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
  feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
  options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
  raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_1_input' with dtype float and shape [?,89]
 [[Node: dense_1_input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,89], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Comment: Try adding `keras.backend.clear_session()` before defining tensorboard callback.